# Integer solutions to $x^2=2y^4+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all integer solutions to $x^2=2y^4+1$.

---

**What I tried**

The only solutions I got are $(\pm 1 ,0)$, I rewrote the question as : is $a_{n}$ a perfect square for $n>0$ were

$$a_0=0,\quad a_1=2, \quad a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n.$$
I tried taking $\pmod{4}$ and $\pmod{12}$ but that led me nowhere.

Comment: Where did you get the recurrence relation ?

Comment: @Shailesh from solving $x^2=2y^2+1$ (pell equation).

Comment: Looking at the solutions modulo $100$, I realized that $y$ must be a multiple of $10$ and the ending digits of $x$ must be $01,49,51\ or\ 99$

Comment: @Peter I used congruence already but it lead me nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no solutions other than those trivial ones. First we note that $x$ must be odd. Let $x = 2k+1$. This gives $2k^2+2k = y^4$. Thus $y = 2j$ and we have $k(k+1) = 8j^4$. Note that $\gcd(k,k+1) = 1$ so we have two cases.

Case 1: $k+1 = 8a^4, k = b^4$.

This case is impossible since this implies $b^4 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$ but $-1$ is a not a quadratic residue $\pmod 4$.

Case 2: $k+1 = b^4, k = 8a^4$.

This case is equivalent to solving the diophantine equation $8a^4+1 = b^4$. An elementary solution is given [here.](http://dspace.nitrkl.ac.in:8080/dspace/bitstream/2080/1845/1/full_paper.pdf) In the referenced paper, it is prove that the only non trivial solution to this equation is $(a,b) = (1,3)$ which gives $k = 8, k+1 = 9$ but $9 = b^4$ is impossible.

Comment: +1. You can prove case 2 directly by noting that $(b^2-1)(b^2+1)=2(2a^2)^2$ implies that one of $b^2-1$ or $b^2+1$ is a square. 
Therefore $b=1$ or $b=0$.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland: only if their gcd is 1. How can we say that their gcd is 1 though?

Comment: No their gcd is 2. Now divide whichever of $b^2-1$ or $b^2+1$ results in odd times even on the left.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Oh thanks! I wonder what that author used all those pages for then...

Comment: Well, $8a^4+1=b^4$ is easier than $8a^4+1=b^2.$

Comment: The link is not working for me.

Comment: $(a,b)=(1,3)$ isn't a solution to $8a^4+1=b^4$, but to $8a^4+1=b^2$; I'm presuming that this is just a transcription error somewhere...