# Does Diophantine equation $1+n+n^2+\dots+n^k=2m^2$ have a solution for $n,k \geq 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures

When studying properties of perfect numbers (specifically [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963181/if-qk-n2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with-special-prime-q-is-sigmaqk-c/4249583#4249583)), I ran into the Diophantine equation
$$
1+n+n^2+\dots+n^k=2m^2, n\geq 2, k \geq 2.
$$
Searching in range $n \leq 10^6$, $k \leq 10^2$ yields no solution. So I wonder if there are any solutions, and if not, is there some elementary reason for that? Or if it can be converted to some known open problem, that would do too...

**Some thoughts:** Of course if we allow $n=1$ or $k=1$ we could get trivial solutions. We can also see by mod $2$ that both $n$ and $k$ must be odd. Now we could try to solve some small cases such as $k=3$ or $k=5$... So set $k=3$ and try to solve $$1+n+n^2+n^3=2m^2.$$ Left side factors and hence we want to solve $(n+1)(n^2+1)=2m^2$. Now this imples $4 \mid 2m^2$ and so $m$ is even. Also we can see that $4 \nmid n^2+1$ for any integer $n$ (becase $n^2\equiv 0,1 \pmod 4 $). So all powers of $2$ in $2m^2$ except one will divide $n+1$. So let $m=2^t r$ with $2 \nmid r$,  then $2m^2=2^{2t+1}r^2$, $2^{2t} \mid n+1$, $2 \mid n^2+1$. So we can put $n=2^{2t}s-1$ with $2 \nmid s$, substitute it back, divide all powers of $2$ and we have the equation
$$
s(2^{4t-1}s^2-2^{2t}s+1)=r^2.
$$
Now the two expressions in the product are coprime, so they both have to be square, and that is farthest I got so far. Also the expression $2^{4t-1}s^2-2^{2t}s+1$ being square has a solution $s=15,t=2$, and I am yet to find another (but of course $s$ is not a square in this case so it does nothing for the original problem).

Comment: $$k=2j+1\implies j(n+1)+1\equiv 2m^2\pmod 3$$ any time $$3\nmid n$$

Comment: If you're lost that means $$n\not\equiv 5\pmod 6$$ and $$k\not\equiv 1\pmod 6$$

Comment: $12m^2>2j^3+3j^2+j$ if I did the math correctly.

Comment: Sorry spamming , but why is $k$ checked to such a low value there are products to create the sum of $k$ values for example $$(1+n)\cdot (1+n^2)\cdot (1+n^4)\cdot (1+n^8)\cdot (1+n^{16})\cdot (1+n^{32})\cdot (1+n^{64})$$ calculates the first $128$ ($0$ through $127$) powers of $n$ summed. You can shift by multiplying by a power of $n$ that way you can get formulae for any $k$.

Comment: I've just found out using searchonmath that this was asked on MO some time ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285507/a-modification-of-the-ljunggren-nagell-equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have $(n,s,x,y)$ with $n,s>1$ odd
$$n^s+1=2x^2\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{n^s-1}{n-1}=y^2,$$
then by a [result of Ljunggren](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206645/on-a-result-attributed-to-w-ljunggren-and-t-nagell), we must have $n=3,s=5$, which gives $x^2=122$. Hence, there are no integral solutions to the system of equations in Theorem $1$ (see below). We conclude that there are no solutions in the positive integers to
$$
\frac{n^{k+1}-1}{n-1}=2m^2
$$
with $n,k\ge 2$.

---

**Theorem 1:** Assume there exists a triple $(n,k,m)$ of positive integers with $n,k\ge 2$
$$\frac{n^{k+1}-1}{n-1}=2m^2.$$
Write $k+1=2^rs$ with $s$ odd. Then $r=1$, and there exist positive integers $x,y$ with
$$
n^s+1=2x^2\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{n^s-1}{n-1}=y^2.
$$

*Proof:* Suppose we have a solution $(n,k,m)$. Write $k+1=2^rs$, then
$$
\frac{n^{2^rs}-1}{n^{s}-1}\cdot \frac{n^s-1}{n-1}=2m^2.
$$
We show that no odd prime divides both factors on the left. Let $p$ be an odd prime, $t=\operatorname{ord}_p\left[n^s-1\right]$, let $g\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a primitive root modulo $p^{t+1}$, and let $\ell\ge 1$ be an integer with $n^s\equiv g^{\ell}\pmod {p^{t+1}}$. Then $\operatorname{ord}_p(\ell)=t-1$. Hence, $\operatorname{ord}_{p}(2^r\ell)=t-1$ and $\operatorname{ord}_p(n^{2^rs}-1)=t$, whence $p$ does not divide $(n^{2^rs}-1)/(n^s-1)$.

By a similar argument, $(n^s-1)/(n-1)$ is odd, which means it must be a perfect square. It follows that there exist positive integers $u,v$ such that $(u,2^r-1,v)$ is a solution (and we can take $u=n^s$). We find that,
$$\prod_{t=0}^{r-1}\left(u^{2^t}+1\right)=\frac{u^{2^r}-1}{u-1}=2v^2.$$
It is very easy to prove that for all integers $t_1\neq t_2$, the greatest common divisor of $u^{2^{t_1}}+1$ and $u^{2^{t_2}}+1$ is a power of $2$. Therefore, each factor in the product on the left is either a perfect square or twice a perfect square.

Assume that $r\ge 2$, then $(u+1)(u^2+1)=u^3+u^2+u+1$ is either a perfect square or twice a perfect square. By Tomita's elliptic curve argument, it cannot be twice a perfect square, so it has to be a perfect square. By the result of Ljunggren, we must have $u=n^s=7$. Because $7^4+1$ is neither a square nor twice a square, we must have $r=2$, so $n=7$ and $k+1=2^rs=4$. However,
$$\frac{7^4-1}{7-1}=400$$
is not twice a perfect square. Therefore, $r=1$. $\square$

Comment: Good progress, thank you. It looks correct as far as I can tell (I still need to think more why $\operatorname{ord}_p(\ell)=t-1$ and $\operatorname{ord}_p(n^{2^rs}-1)=t$ but the rest I've got).

Comment: @Sil I've corrected the two typos. Regarding the $\operatorname{ord}_p$ question, note that $g$ is a also a primitive root modulo $p^t$, and that $g^\ell\equiv n^s\equiv 1\pmod{p^t}$. Therefore, $(p-1)p^{t-1}\mid \ell$. Therefore, if $p^{t}\mid \ell$, then $(p-1)p^t\mid \ell$, which would imply that $g^\ell\equiv n^s\equiv 1\pmod {p^{t+1}}$ and $p^{t+1}\mid n^s-1$. This contradicts the definition of $t$ and thus, $\operatorname{ord}_p(\ell)=t-1$.

Comment: Shouldn't $g^\ell\equiv 1\pmod{p^t}$ imply $\ell \mid \varphi(p^t)$ (provided $l$ is the order of $g$), but you use it the other way around as $\varphi(p^t) \mid \ell$?

Comment: @Sil View $g$ as an element of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^t\mathbb{Z})^\times$. This group is cyclic of order $\varphi(p^t)$ and $g$ is a generator, which means that $g$ has order $\varphi(p^t)$. If $g^\ell\equiv 1$ for some $\ell$, then the order of $g$ divides $\ell$, so $\varphi(p^t)\mid \ell$.

Comment: Oh right, the order being $\varphi(p^t)$ does the trick, you convinced me :)

Comment: The paper [On The Nagell-Ljunggren Equation](https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/15038/13033/) claims that Ljunggren proved (finished) that $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=y^q$ has no solution if $q=2$ other than $\frac{3^5-1}{3-1}=11^2$, $\frac{7^4-1}{7-1}=20^2$. That seems to be the missing piece, unless I am missing something?

Comment: @Sil Yes! I'll incorporate it into my answer and make it a complete proof

Comment: @Sil Done! If you are satisfied with the proof, please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: Accepted, thank you again - very nice work!

Comment: Just revisiting this, how do you conclude in the very last paragraph that $u+1$ must be a square? We have only established that $u^2+1$ must be twice a square, and for $u+1$ we know must be a square or twice a square as well (it seems as if $v$ being odd was used, but $v$ must be even for $r \geq 2$).

Comment: @Sil There was a mistake there, good you caught it. Should be correct now (only rewrote the final paragraph)

Answer (score 4):

$1+n+n^2+n^3=2m^2$ can be transformed to $y^2 = x^3+2x^2+4x+8$ with $x=2n$ and $y=4m.$

The equation $y^2 = x^3+2x^2+4x+8$ is an elliptic curve which has one torsion point $(x,y)=(-2,0)$ and the rank of curve is $0$.

Since rank is $0$, so there are no rational points of infinite order on the curve.
The only integral point is torsion point $(x,y)=(-2,0)$ .

Thus, there are no positive integral solution.

```
           sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,2,0,4,8])
           sage: E.rank()
           0
           sage: E.torsion_points()
           [(-2 : 0 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0)]
```

Comment: "there are no rational points on the curve and only integral point is..." : I don't get it. Integral points are rational points. And the rank being zero doesn't mean the curve has no rational points.

Comment: $E(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}^{r}\oplus E_{\rm{torsion}}(\mathbb{Q})$,
$E_{\rm{torsion}}(\mathbb{Q})$is the finite torsion subgroup and $r$ is the rank of the elliptic curve.  
The rank is the size of the set of rational points of infinite order.  
Hence rank $0$ means there is no rational points of infinite order.

Comment: Nice, this seems to resolve case $k=3$, though I guess it does not generalize to higher $k$'s - well assuming the Sage gives us all integral solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary proof that $1+n+n^2+n^3=2m^2$ has only integer solution $(n,m)=(-1,0)$. This is the minimal case referred in the general proof and this post gives an alternative without using the elliptic curves.

Since $(n+1)(n^2+1)=2m^2$ and gcd of the expressions on the left is $2$ (by parity argument $n$ must be odd, and $4 \nmid n^2+1$), we thus have $n^2+1$ either square of twice a square. It cannot be a square unless $n=0$ (which does not solve the original equation), hence $n^2+1=2a^2$, and so $n+1=b^2$. As $n$ is odd $b$ is even, say $b=2c$. Thus $n=4c^2-1$ and plugging to the previous equation we get $(4c^2-1)^2+1=2a^2$. However with some manipulation this can be written as:
$$
(2c^2-1)^2+(2c^2)^2=a^2.
$$
This is a primitive [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) ($2c^2$ and $2c^2-1$ are coprime). It implies $2c^2=2\alpha \beta$, $2c^2-1=\alpha^2-\beta^2$ for some coprime integers $\alpha, \beta$. But then $c^2=\alpha \beta$ and $\alpha=\gamma^2$, $\beta=\delta^2$ for some integers $\gamma$, $\delta$. Plugging to the other equation we get $2\gamma^2 \delta^2-1=\gamma^4-\delta^4$. We rewrite this as $(\delta^2+\gamma^2)^2=2\gamma^4+1$, now we are ready to use the following lemma:

**Lemma.** Only integer solutions to $x^2=2y^4+1$ are $(x,y)=(\pm 1,0)$.

**Proof.** There is an elementary proof on this site already, see [Integer solutions to $x^2=2y^4+1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402798/integer-solutions-to-x2-2y41?noredirect=1). It was also the Problem 4 on China IMO Team Selection Test in 1993, see this [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h42566p269097). Here is a proof based on ideas in linked posts/comments:

> Clearly $y=0$ is a solution with $x=\pm 1$, so assume $y \neq 0$. Since $x$ is odd, put $x=2k+1$. The equation becomes $2k(k+1)=y^4$. Hence $y=2z$ and $k(k+1)=8z^4$. Since $\gcd(k,k+1)=1$, one of $k,k+1$ is fourth power and the other is $8$ times a fourth power.
>
> If $k+1 = 8a^4, k = b^4$, then $b^4=8a^4-1 \equiv -1 \pmod 8$, impossible.
>
> If $k+1 = b^4, k = 8a^4$, we can write $8a^4=(b^4-1)=(b^2-1)(b^2+1)$. Since $4 \nmid b^2+1$, it's clear that $\gcd(b^2-1,b^2+1) = 2$ and we have $a^4=\frac{b^2-1}{4} \frac{b^2+1}{2}$. Then $b^2-1=4t^2=(2t)^2$ and so $b=\pm 1$. But then $a=0$, impossible since $y \neq 0$.

So by the Lemma with $x=\delta^2+\gamma^2$ and $y=\gamma$, we have $\gamma=0$ and $\delta^2=1$. By a backwards substitution $\alpha=0, \beta=1$, then $c^2=0$ and finally $n=-1$ is the only solution (with $m=0$).